# Why is this object not being added to this array?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a method that generates a `PFObject` and stores it in an `NSMutableArray`. Then a tableview populates itself with this array. However, the method that stores the `PFObject` is not successfully adding the object. Here is the method:

```
- (void)addListing{
    PFObject* userListing = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"userListing"];
    [userListing setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"John Smith"] forKey:@"userName"];
    [userListing setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"408 521 3322"] forKey:@"userPhoneNumber"];
    [userListing setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet"] forKey:@"listingName"];
    [userListing setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$10"] forKey:@"listingPrice"];

    [listings addObject:userListing]; 
    [userListing saveInBackground];

    NSLog(@"%i", listings.count);
}
```

On that last line, I have the console print the amount of objects that are stored in listings but it repeatedly prints zero. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you certain that listings is non-nil when this method is called? nil would also respond with 0 for a count method call.

Comment: Yep, almost certainly you never created the array for `listings`.

Comment: Understand that `setObject` on a nil pointer will quietly no-op, and `count` will return zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are initializing the array.

```
listings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```